# CSS not being applied as soon as we resize the window. It's only applied on scroll

Tags: css, angularjs

I am using angular way to apply css but it doesn't get applied whenever resize the window. canvas height is changed on resize window but table height only being applied when we scroll the window. I want to set the same height of canvas as soon as we resize the window.

How can I fix this?

```
 angular.element(document).ready(function ($timeout) {

  function update_table_height(canvasHeight) {
      angular.element('.scrollableContainer').css("height", canvasHeight + 5 + "px");
  }

  angular.element(window).on("load resize scroll", function() {
    var canvasHeight = angular.element('#chartCanvas').height();     
    update_table_height(canvasHeight);
  });

  $timeout(function(){
    var canvasHeight = angular.element('#chartCanvas').height();
    update_table_height(canvasHeight);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did it with help of directive. Please suggest is that okay?

in *index.html*

```
 <div class="ibox-content" match-window-height="['#chartCanvas']">
```

in *app.directive.js*

```
.directive('matchWindowHeight', function($timeout, $window) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, el, attrs)  {
                var window = angular.element($window);

                scope.$watch(function () {
                    var attribute = scope.$eval(attrs['matchWindowHeight']);
                    var targetElem = angular.element(document.querySelector(attribute[0]));
                    return targetElem.height();
                },
                function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    if (newValue != oldValue) {
                        el.css('height', newValue + 40 );
                    }
                });
                window.bind('load resize', function () {
                    scope.$apply();
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need another timeout to wait for the render.

Maybe like this:

```
angular.element(window).on("load resize scroll", function() {
 updateHeight();
});

function updateHeight(){

  $timeout(function(){
    var canvasHeight = angular.element('#chartCanvas').height();
    table_height(canvasHeight);
  });
}

// updateHeight on load
updateHeight();
```

Comment: not working buddy. i have updated my code as per your suggestion

Comment: Bummer...Is the resize event fired at all?

Comment: And console.log(canvasHeight) does show a changed value on resize?

Comment: actually it does not show the new canvas height untill we scroll.

Comment: can we use `$scope.$watch` or something like that